# Does Crate IO database supports backup from one cluster and restore to different cluster?

Tags: database, cratedb

If we persist snapshots from one cluster, is it possible to restore these snapshots in different Crate IO cluster? If it has same schema?

Answer (score 0):

yes - to some extent. With the `CREATE REPOSITORY` command you can register existing repositories with CrateDB, and the `sys.snapshots` table tells you about the available snapshots in that table. With `RESTORE SNAPSHOT` you can then restore the table. However, to restore a full table, the table has to be dropped anyway, so ...  ; restoring partitions of a table might work though.

Read more here: https://crate.io/docs/reference/en/latest/sql/snapshot_restore.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't seem to be possible because to restore snapshots, a repository needs to be created. When you try to create the same repository in the new Crate Cluster point to the old repository it will say that the repository already exists so you can't restore the snapshots from the previous Crate cluster